# Ruby: Variable initialization within classes

Tags: ruby, class, initialization, instance-variables

Having some trouble when it comes to initializing variables within a class (instance variables etc.) and I was wondering if anybody could clarify the proper syntax for me.

Sample code:

```
Class Pets
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name=name
    end

    def name=(name)
        @name = name
        #I believe this is where I change @name instance variable
    end
    #in this space I could create more <methods> for Class.new.<method>
end
```

My question is do I need to have `attr_accessor` as well as `def initialize` and `def name=`?

In addition, if I have multiple attr_accessors do I need to add them as arguments to `def initialize`, e.g.:

```
Class Pets
    attr_accessor :name :age :color

    def initialize(name, age, color)
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @color = color

 #and if this is the case do I need methods for each (name= age= color= etc.)
end
```

One last thing:
If someone could confirm or deny my thought process on the `name=` `age=` and `color=` type of methods within the classes. Am I correct in thinking `method=` is necessary to change the instance variable? I am a bit unsure about what the `method=` is for and why I cannot change the instance variable within initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor :symbol` do the same as `attr_writer :symbol` and `attr_reader :symbol`, i.e. it creates both reader (`def symbol; @symbol; end`) and writer (`def symbol=(value); @symbol = value; end`).

Initialize is a method called every time new instance of the class is being created. It is not the same as `new` method as some classes may have its own custom factory methods. You don't need to define your initialize method, only problem is that then `symbol` reader would return `nil`, as the local variable would not been set.

In ruby everything is a method. In case of objects, `object.attr = value` is just a short for `object.attr=(value)` where `attr=` is just another method. (Similarly `<<` operator is defined as a method on Array class, `attr_accessor` is a method defined on class "Class").

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I have seen some examples where the code does not include a `method=` value but instead something along the lines of `def method (argument)` /n  `@instance variable` so I was confused as to why I needed to use the `method=`. For clarification, I am doing an rspec tutorial and when I took the `=` out of the `method=` the tests did not pass. I, therefore, assumed that it was always necessary. How would I go about defining multiple instance variables (as in the second section of code)?

Comment: You just go with `attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr 3 ...`

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back on what what said earlier, recall that if you want your attributes to be accessible outside your class (you want to write over the attribute value or you want to read it) you will need to use the attr_accessor (or attr_writer or attr_reader).

If I had a class like ...

```
class Calendar
  attr_reader :event_name, :all_events

  def initialize
    @event_name = event_name
    @all_events = [] 
  end

 def create_event(event_name)
   puts "#{event_name} has been added to your calendar."
   @all_events << event_name
   p @all_events
 end

 def see_all_events
   puts "Here are your events --"
   @all_events.each {|event| puts "- #{event}"}
 end

end

my_calendar=Calendar.new
my_calendar.create_event("interview")
my_calendar.see_all_events
my_calendar.all_events
```

I can read all my events either with the method see_all_events or by calling all_events on my  class Calendar object. If for some reason I did not want a see_all_events method but instead only wanted it to be seen by calling all_events on my object I can only do this because of attr_reader.

Basically the point here is to remember exactly how you want your users to interact with your object attributes. If it needs to be private and only accessed via methods then you should be weary of using attr_accessor or attr_writer or attr_reader (depending on the situation).